# Spring boot response body is showing empty in PostMan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I am using @Valid annotation to validate some of my model properties. It is working as expected, if any data is not provided as per the expectation it is throwing back 400 Bad Request error. But the response body is always coming as empty.

My Controller Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bnpp.leavemanagement.exception.DepartmentNotFoundException;
import com.bnpp.leavemanagement.exception.EmployeeAlreadyExistsException;
import com.bnpp.leavemanagement.exception.EmployeeNotFoundException;
import com.bnpp.leavemanagement.model.EmployeeModel;
import com.bnpp.leavemanagement.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController 
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;
    
    
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeModel> createEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid EmployeeModel empNew) throws  EmployeeAlreadyExistsException, DepartmentNotFoundException, EmployeeNotFoundException
    {
        EmployeeModel resEmp = empService.addEmployee(empNew);
        return new ResponseEntity( resEmp, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Model Class Property

```
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  @NotEmpty(message = "FirstName cannot be empty")
  private String firstName = null;
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:leavemgmt
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

server.port=8443

server.ssl.key-alias=leavemanagement
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:leavemanagement.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=password

server.error.include-message=always
server.error.include-binding-errors=always
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
```

[image: PostMan Response]

Please help me on what to be done to get the response body in Postman on any validation failure.

Comment: share your service layer too,

Comment: Share service and repository classes as well

Comment: For starters remove `@Validated` from the controller you don't need it. The `@Valid` on the method argument is enough.

Comment: I have removed the @Validated from the controller as directed but still the scenario stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your errors in your response using `BindingResult` like this in your controller:

```
 public ResponseEntity<EmployeeModel> createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeModel empNew,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
  if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
   {
     for(FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            //you can define your ErrorMOdel dto here and add  
          //fieldError properties then add the whole errorList in 
          //your response.
         //Finally, return the response from here
        }
   }

  //if there is no errors in your request: execute this part:
   EmployeeModel resEmp = empService.addEmployee(empNew);
        return new ResponseEntity( resEmp, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

**Update according to your need:**
You can define your `EmployeeModel` in this way:

```
public class EmployeeModel<T> implements Serializable
{
  //your previously defined entities here
     private List<T> errorList;  //this is new one to show errors

    //constructors, setters, getters
}
```

Now, when you get error, replace the previous code with this:

```
if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
       {
         EmployeeModel response= new EmployeeModel();
         for(FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) 
            {
               response.setErrorList(bindingResult.getFieldErrors());
            }
           return new ResponseEntity( response, 
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
       }
```

**Further improvisation you can carry on:** 
You can add another field as status in your `EmpoloyeeModel`, `status` will be set as `success` when there is no error, otherwise, set to `error` i.e `employeeModel.setStatus("success") or.setStatus("error")` depending on the situation
Better, write a generic Response class to hold all type of response like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ServiceResponse<T> implements Serializable {
private HttpStatus status; //OK_Failure
private StatusCode statusCode; //code
private T body;
private List<T> errorList;
}
```

Let me know if you face any problem regarding this.

Comment: This looks like the proper way to handle the scenario I am stuck up with. But am confused how can I map the response type to EmployeeModel type as I am not going to return the EmployeeModel just like the success case. If it is not too much to ask, can you please provide me an example on how to map the EmployeeModelDTO and return the error response object??

Comment: Am simply asking what will the code look like in the provided code context below without changing my return type from ResponseEntity<EmployeeModel> ```//you can define your ErrorMOdel dto here and add  
          //fieldError properties then add the whole errorList in 
          //your response.
         //Finally, return the response from here```

Comment: @harish, please check my updated ans. If this helps, you can accept it as accepted answer

Comment: Shouldn't spring boot handle the default response automatically ? I am also facing similar issue , and I do not want to add additional code for the same, what's the point of mentioning a message attribute in the @notNull annotation then ?

Comment: @Harsh, yes spring boot handles that automatically too. If you want to customize your response you can follow this, otherwise leave it to spring boot. Both options are okay

Comment: Unfortunately, I understand but I only get a error code and no response body while I hit from postman

Comment: you can ask in separate question with details of your problems otherwise it is very tough to find the actual issue here